# как получить разницу двух массивов javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два массива

```
[{id:1, name:"vasya"}, {id:2, name:"Vova"}]
[{id:3, name:"petya"}, {id:2, name:"Vova"}, {id:1, name:"vasya"}]
```

Как мне получить элемент {id:3 , name:"petya"} , если объекты в массиве могут рандомно размещаться в массиве и по индексу сравнивать не вариант

Comment: просто сравнить через for больший массив с меньшим

Comment: да я понял, но как лучше реализовать не могу сложить алгоритм

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [{id:1, name:"vasya"}, {id:2, name:"Vova"}]
var b = [{id:3, name:"petya"}, {id:2, name:"Vova"}, {id:1, name:"vasya"}]

var q, temp=Object.create(null), res=[]

for (q=0; q<a.length; ++q)
  temp[a[q].id] = a[q]

for (q=0; q<b.length; ++q)
  if (b[q].id in temp)
    delete temp[b[q].id]
  else
    temp[b[q].id] = b[q]

for (q in temp)
  res.push(temp[q])

console.log(res)
```

Ну или через `Object.hasOwnProperty`, если старые браузеры нужны.

---

Ещё вариант: сортировать по id и использовать алгоритм слияния.